# How come html_entity_decode is not working?

Tags: php, decode, decoding

I am having a lot of trouble trying to decode the html in my database columns. Each column in my table has the potential to include something that needs to be decoded. For example `&#x2f;` to `/` is one of the many that needs to be decoded. I am pretty bad at php. My code does not do the decoding. Please help.

```
<?php   
        $connection = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass);

        if(!$connection)
        {
            die("Database server connection failed.");  
        }
        else
        {
            $dbconnect = mysql_select_db($db, $connection);

            if(!$dbconnect)
            {
                die("Unable to connect to the specified database!");
            }
            else
            {
                $query = "SELECT * FROM Table WHERE area='ON'";

                $resultset = mysql_query($query, $connection);

                $records = array();

                while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultset))
                {
                    $records[] = $r;        
                }


                mysqli_close($connection);
                json_encode($records);
                echo html_entity_decode($records);
            }   
        }
?>
```

Comment: You have to store the JSON decoded string back to the variable, e.g. `$records = json_encode($records);`.

Comment: How has this HTML encoded data got into your database? If you put it there then you're probably doing something seriously wrong.